# Secondary construction syntax kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following kotlin class with a primary constructor,

```
class Person(first: String, last: String, age: Int){ 

    init{
        println("Initializing")
    }

}
```

I'd like to add a secondary constructor that parses a fullname into a `first` and `last` name and calls the primary constructor.  However, I can't get the syntax right...

```
class Person(first: String, last: String, age: Int){  

    // Secondary constructor
    constructor(fullname: String, age: Int):
        this("first", "last", age)
        {
            println("In secondary constructor")
        }

    init{
        println("Initializing")
    }
}
```

This works fine, because I'm not actually parsing `fullname` in the secondary constructor.  When I go ahead and try to parse fullname,

```
constructor(fullname: String, age: Int):
var first = fullname.split()[0];
...
{
    println("In secondary constructor")
}
```

I get an unresolved reference: fullname.  It doesn't exist in scope, but if I put it in the braces, then I cannot call the primary constructor via `this`,

```
constructor(fullname: String, age: Int):
{
    var first = fullname
    this(first, "foo", age)
    println("In secondary constructor")
}
```

I get an error involving a missing `invoke` function.

Can't find a good example of this case on Kotlin docs, sorry.

Comment: You could always expose factory methods and delegate those as opposed to constructors, allowing you to decide when to actually delegate, or just don't declare variables for `first` and `last` in your second constructor. But if you don't mind me asking, why must you expose `Person(first, last, age)` AND `Person(full name, age)`? What if the client forgets to add a space between first and last when using `fullName`? You cannot declare a variable before constructor delegation.

Comment: This is just a toy example, I wouldn't actually build these two constructors.  Are you saying I can't use a secondary constructor this way?
In plain java, I thought you could declare variables in secondary constructors?  So I guess this is just a bad example, and it's hitting on a use case that good coding would avoid?

Comment: Yes, you cannot use secondary constructor this way. `this` is a delegation, which is why you can't use it within the braces. You'd have to do something along the lines of `constructor(...) : this(fullName.split(" ")[0], fullName.split(" ")[1])` which has potential for indexing out of bounds.

Comment: So if I had the use case that I had very complex validation of "fullName", I'd just have a mess on my hands?

Comment: Precisely. Why do you want to expose `constructor(fullName)` in the first place? The only situation I can think of is reading from IO, but if that's the case, it's up to the system that's parsing IO data to split the first and last name. The name should be split by the time it reaches `Person`, it sn't the responsibility of the `Person` class, and implementing this can actually harm reusability (what if you had 2-word last name? The tuba player John Van Houten would have issues using that constructor, assuming he didn't want "Van" to be his last name, nor wants to exclude it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I use when I want a secondary constructor that needs to perform some calculations before passing the results to the primary constructor is to a function on the companion object. The code to do this would look like:

```
class Person(first: String, last: String, age: Int) {  

    companion object {
        fun fromFullNameAndAge(fullname: String, age: Int) : Person {
          println("In secondary constructor")
          var bits = fullname.split()
          // Additional error checking can (and should) go in here.
          return Person(bits[0],bits[1],age)
        }
    }

    init{
        println("Initializing")
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this

```
var p = Person.fromFullNameAndAge("John Doe", 27)
```

Which is not as neat as `Person("John Doe", 27)` but is IMO not too bad.

Comment: Ok, thank you Micahel.  This kind of reminds me of python for some reason.  I remember making constructors that are also called like static methods.

Comment: Next thing you know, your API is flooded with static factory methods that perform corner case checks. What if you wanted to add a social security number later on, or maybe change how names are parsed? Would be forced to violate some pretty useful principles, such as Open/Close

Comment: @VinceEmigh Often the constructor / factory function is _exactly_ the place you want corner case checks, being far better than littering those checks in a dozen places throughout your code. But, as always, it is a matter of balance. I would advocate against blindly creating factory functions for every case - but if it's a pattern that crops up several times - then a case can certainly be made for it.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson It wouldn't be littered around the code, it would be handled by an object responsible for it (in this case, a parser). This factory is embedding parsing rules into the contract of `Person`, harming it's reusability. What if they wanted to expose a `Person(title, first, last, age)`? Now you need a `fromFullNameAndAgeAndTitle`.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor calls via `this` must be the first call. This is why it's handled as a delegate, rather than a normal method invocation. This means you cannot declare variables before the call is delegated.

You can solve this by simply inlining whatever values you planned on storing in variables:

```
constructor(fullName : String, age : int) : this(fullName.split(" ")[0], fullName.split(" ")[1])
```

But this can potentially index out of bounds if a last name wasn't specified, or if the client decided to use `-` or some other character as the delimiter. On top of that, it's an eye sore.

## Design Analysis

The issue with your structure is giving the `Person` class the responsibility of determining the first and last name. This deteriorates the reusability of that class, as it'll be limited to one form of parsing. This is why the parsing of names should not be carried out by `Person`.

Instead, you should expose your primary constructor, then have the client of `Person` separate the first and last name.

## Solution Example

Imagine we were reading names from a file. Each line in the file consists of a full name.

```
nameFile.forEachLine({ personList.add(Person(it)) })
```

This is the luxury you are attempting to give your clients: allow them to simply input a name, without worrying about parsing it.

The problem with this is the lack of safety: what if the line only contained a first name? What if the file didn't use whitespace to separate first and last name? You'd be forced to define new `Person` types just to handle different first/last name combinations.

Instead, the parsing should occur outside of the class:

```
file.forEachLine({
    val firstName = ...
    val secondName = ...

    personList.add(Person(firstName, secondName))
})
```

Now that the responsibility has been taken out of `Person`, we can give the responsibility to a new object if we wanted:

```
val parser = NameParser(" ") //specify delimiter
file.forEachLine({
    val firstName = parser.extractFirstName(it)
    val lastName = parser.extractLastName(it)

    personList.add(Person(firsrName, lastName))
})
```